# NSSearchField - Display an NSMenu with results

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I'm trying to figure out how to display results of search below my search field. I suppose the cause is that my program never receives the message

```
-(NSArray *)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView completions:(NSArray *)words forPartialWordRange:(NSRange)charRange indexOfSelectedItem:(int*)index;
```

So I can never return any results.

However, I **do** receive

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)obj;
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)commandSelector;
```

Any chances what the cause may be? I did set the delegate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your delegate won't receive the `completions:` message unless `complete` gets called at some point on the field editor of the text field. In `controlTextDidChange:` you can do this:

```
- (void)controlTextDidChange:(NSNotification *)note {

    NSTextView * fieldEditor = [[note userInfo] objectForKey:@"NSFieldEditor];

    [fieldEditor complete];
}
```

You will, without a doubt, have to make this more sophisticated (when your delegate returns the list of completions, `controlTextDidChange:` will be called again, creating an infinite loop), but that should get you started.

Comment: Oh god damnit, I've been searching for hours. Yes, this is absolutely the solution! Thanks a lot!